# how to use arduino multi Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, arduino, network-programming

I have Arduino with ESP8266 module.

I thought "How about making arduino echo(?) client?".

So, I made **multithread server** that have read & write functions.

Now, I have to make arduino client using multithread, with one thread sending data to the server and another receiving data.

But, Arduino can't use thread.

Is there a way to use the Thread?

Comment: Did you look to [ArduinoThread](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread) ?

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly, i have been trying for a while by I have found no work-arounds. Although, you can proto thread. It's not nearly as efficient, but can work

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Arduino does not support multithread programming.

However there have been some workarounds, for example the one in [this project](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread) (you can install it also from the Arduino IDE).

I think it can be suitable for your project, although it seems you have to define the schedule time yourself while in a real multithread environment it is the OS that decides when to execute tasks.

Let me know if it works for your project.